# Visual Studio 2008 Deploying To Intermec CK3

Tags: visual-studio-2008, intermec

I want to know what I am doing wrong.

I have an application on an old old labtop that uses Visual Studio 2008.  The emulation to run the application is debug is working as intended.

The issue is, when I try to bring this app over to the actual intermec ck3 scanner, it acts as if it is not connected. Although it is.

On the app, I check for a group of subnets to figure out what location the scanner is being used at.  If it cannot detect it, it gives ??? for the IP address and the location.

When I run this app through the debugger on the old labtop it finds the IP no problem.. But then when I bring over the .exe to the scanner it does not find anything and gives me the ???... But, maybe this is where I am going wrong.  I am used to compiling an application and it creating some kind of file, and then moving that file to the device it will be used on.

This does not seem to be the case.. As I only see Build Solution/Rebuild Solution/Deploy Solution/Clean Solution and Build MyApp/Rebuild MyApp/Deploy MyApp/Clean MyApp.. as options underneath the Build Tab in Visual Studio 2008.

Can anybody help me out or point me in the right direction? Please do not downvote this or instantly mark it as a duplicate without telling me why...

Thank you :)

This is the code used to find the IP address:

```
Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        Dim hostentry As Net.IPHostEntry = Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Net.Dns.GetHostName())
        If hostentry IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim collectionOfIPs As Net.IPAddress() = hostentry.AddressList
            MessageBox.Show(collectionOfIPs(0).ToString())
            strSubnet = collectionOfIPs(0).ToString()
            If strSubnet.StartsWith("172.18.46.") Or strSubnet.StartsWith("172.18.51.") Or strSubnet.StartsWith("172.18.49.") Or strSubnet.StartsWith("172.18.61.") Or strSubnet.StartsWith("172.18.62.") Then
                strSubnet = "NOR " & Now.Month.ToString & "/" & Now.Day.ToString
                'ElseIf strSubnet.StartsWith("10.79.255.") Or strSubnet.StartsWith("172.24.148.") Or strSubnet.StartsWith("172.24.149.") Or strSubnet.StartsWith("172.24.150.") Or strSubnet.StartsWith("172.24.151.") Or strSubnet.StartsWith("10.73.61.") Or strSubnet.StartsWith("10.73.62.") Then
                '    strSubnet = "DAK " & Now.Month.ToString & "/" & Now.Day.ToString
            ElseIf strSubnet.StartsWith("10.48.3.") Or strSubnet.StartsWith("10.68.8") Then
                strSubnet = "DEX " & Now.Month.ToString & "/" & Now.Day.ToString
            ElseIf strSubnet.StartsWith("172.20.3.") Or strSubnet.StartsWith("172.18.209") Or strSubnet.StartsWith("172.18.208.") Then
                strSubnet = "RRP " & Now.Month.ToString & "/" & Now.Day.ToString
            Else
                strSubnet = "??? " & collectionOfIPs(0).ToString()
            End If
            Me.Text = strSubnet
        End If
    End Sub
```

From the [Dns.GetHostEntry Method Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998(v=vs.110).aspx) is says that if an empty string is passed in for the DNS name, it will use the IPV4 address of the local host.  Which is probably the problem... Maybe I just need a networking guy to look at my scanner? lol

Comment: It appears it is trying to access the .DLL files on a shared account, then if when I switch to the scanner, its on a different network which restricts the DLLs from being found... More to come hopefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I did the build, it was being put onto a shared folder, when I changed the network I was connecting to on the labtop I did the build from, I could see the errors saying it could not access the DLLs... Which is also the reason it wouldnt work on the scanner.

I wanted them in shared locations being of the multiple locations, this way each location needed a port opened through the firewall to access the information!